# Wrong password using auth::attempt in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Sorry for broken english.

I try to login using auth::attempt in laravel, but the return is always wrong password.

my password is

```
12345
```

here's my code :

```
  if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $result = array('msg' => 'Username tidak tersedia !');
    }
    else
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password]))
        {
            $result = array('msg' => 'success');
        }
        else
        {
            $result = array('msg' => 'Password tidak benar, silakan ulangi !');//wrong password
        }
    }
    //return message to view
    echo json_encode($result);
```

what is the format of auth::attempt ? is it hashing ?

Comment: laravel doesnt login with a username by default it uses the email associated with the user.

Comment: Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't login with 'username' by default. The auth::attempt method looks for the email address associated with the user.

> Unless you have customized it.

The correct solution would be

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
{
  $result = array('msg' => 'success');
}
else
{
  $result = array('msg' => 'Password tidak benar, silakan ulangi !');//wrong password
}
```

> You would need to update your form to post through an email address instead

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        $result = array('msg' => 'success');
}
$result = array('msg' => 'Password tidak benar, silakan ulangi !');//wrong password
```

**Note**
I am getting the username and password from a form which is submitted through a post request when the form is submitted I call the function in the controller to log the user in.

Hopefully, this helps with your question.

Comment: $request->input('username') and $request->username is the same thing

Comment: Do you have a username column in the table which is unique?